# how to eliminate blurry text when zooming with translateZ

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

Im having a problem with text inside a div element that is being blurred when handling 3d transformations with translateZ. The transformation is done within javascript.

What I have tried:

```
div.blurryTextDiv {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

and

```
div.blurryTextDiv {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

but none of these methods worked.

This is what the actually transformation looks like:

```
function onParentClick () {

    document.getElementById("parentOfDiv").style.transform = "translateZ(500px)";

}
```

And this is how my html is structured:

```
<figure id="parentOfDiv" onclick="onParentClick()">
  <div id="moreContent" class="blurryTextDiv">why is this text so blurry</div>
</figure>
```

I do not know if this matters but the div element with the blurry text is actually not being transformed, the parent of the div however is being transformed and zoomed in on thus causing the div to zoom with it, thus causing the blurry text.

Is there anyway to alleviate the blurry text of my div?

Please help! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the code of the actual transforms and the html?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but it happened the same to me when I had `transform scale` operations that had decimal points... so I had to write an extra js code to round those numbers and re apply an Integer number on the `transform`... I would also like if there is a better solution, but that may be a work around for you.

Comment: I have edited my question to give more info about the transformations and structure

Comment: Thanks for your insight David! Im not sure that that is the case here since I have no decimals in my transformations and I am not applying the scale transformation to any of my elements.